# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object

Tags: python, recursion, python-3.5

Was looking to so many examples here regarding this problem, but I cannot sort it out for my example.

Any suggestion will be appreciated, I am already having a headache with this recursion.

```
tree = {}

def populate_node(account):
    node = '%(LOGIN)s,%(server_id)s' % account
    tree[node]['login'] = account['LOGIN']
    tree[node]['email'] = account['EMAIL'].lower()
    tree[node]['server_id'] = account['server_id']

for account in accounts:
    node = '%(LOGIN)s,%(server_id)s' % account
    parent = None
    if account['AGENT_ACCOUNT']:
        parent = '%(AGENT_ACCOUNT)s,%(server_id)s' % account
    if node not in tree:
        tree[node] = {}
    populate_node(account)
    if parent:
        tree[node]['parent'] = parent
        if parent not in tree:
            tree[parent] = {
                'login': parent,
                'server_id': account['server_id'],
                'children': [node],
            }
        else:
            if 'children' not in tree[parent]:
                tree[parent]['children'] = [node]
            else:
                tree[parent]['children'].append(node)

def get_path(node, tree):
    parent = node.get('parent')
    node_login = str(str(node.get('login')) + ',' + str(node.get('server_id')))
    if not parent:
       return []
    elif parent == node_login:
       return [parent]
    path = get_path(tree[parent], tree)
    return [parent] + path


for k, v in tree.items():
      v['path'] = get_path(v, tree)
      v['level'] = len(v['path']) + (1 if v['login'] != v.get('parent') else 0)
```

By default :

```
tree = {}
```

node is an item of `tree`.

sample tree:

```
tree = {
    '1987,mt4-demo-0': {
        'login': 1987,
        'email': 'email_1',
        'server_id': 'mt4-demo-0'
    },
    '16044,mt4-demo-0': {
        'login': 16044,
        'email': 'email_2',
        'server_id': 'mt4-demo-0'
    },
    '160877748,mt4-demo-0': {
        'login': 160877748,
        'email': 'email_3',
        'server_id': 'mt4-demo-0'
    }
}
```

And I am getting every time this recursion error

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object
```

Comment: 1) What are `node` and `tree`? 2) Where do you use Tornado?

Comment: Can a node be parent of his parent?

Comment: @LutzHorn tree = {} node is an item of tree

Comment: For `tree = {}` the loop should do nothing. Please include a sample of `tree` that throws this error.

Comment: @LutzHorn tree looks like this tree = {
    'parent_1': {'login': login_1},
    'parent_2': {'login': login_2},
    'parent_3': {'login': login_3},
}

Comment: We'll need a sample `tree` input to diagnose, as well as expected output.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i addead a real sample of tree, as well added all code for creation of the tree

Comment: @MartijnPieters the out is the same tree + addeing the deep of the node v['path'] = get_path(v, tree) and  v['level'] = len(v['path']) + (1 if v['login'] != v.get('parent') else 0)

Comment: @ionluchian: for the given `tree = {...}` values, all 3 produce an empty list. Do you have anything that'll reproduce the exception? I note that none of those have `parent` or `children` keys.

Comment: Basically, you have a circular loop in your accounts somewhere. Something where `AGENT_ACCOUNT` for `login1` points to another `login2`, and the other `login2` has an `AGENT_ACCOUNT` that points to `login1`, either directly or indirectly. Perhaps you need to add a `seen` set and test any new `node_login` strings against that set.

Comment: As a side note: the `v['login'] != v.get('parent')` is **always** going to be true, because `parent` is a string containing `login,server_id`, but `login` is always just a login. Perhaps you wanted `0 if v.get('parent', '').partition(',')[0] == v['login'] else 1`? Or simpler still, `key == v.get('parent')`, because then you involve the `server_id` in the test too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code assumes you are always dealing with an [*acyclic* directed graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), but your input has at least one [directed cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph#Directed_cycle_graph) in it, where one `AGENT_ACCOUNT` reference directly or indirectly points to another account that in turn has an `AGENT_ACCOUNT` value pointing back to the first account.

For example, if `accounts` is set to:

```
accounts = [
    {'LOGIN': 'foo', 'EMAIL': 'foo@bar.com', 'server_id': 'server 1',
     'AGENT_ACCOUNT': 'bar'},
    {'LOGIN': 'bar', 'EMAIL': 'bar@bar.com', 'server_id': 'server 1',
     'AGENT_ACCOUNT': 'foo'}]
```

then `tree` becomes:

```
{'bar,server 1': {'children': ['foo,server 1'],
                  'email': 'bar@bar.com',
                  'login': 'bar',
                  'parent': 'foo,server 1',
                  'server_id': 'server 1'},
 'foo,server 1': {'children': ['bar,server 1'],
                  'email': 'foo@bar.com',
                  'login': 'foo',
                  'parent': 'bar,server 1',
                  'server_id': 'server 1'}}
```

Note that `foo` has an `AGENT_ACCOUNT` that points to `bar`, and `bar` points back to `foo`, forming a cycle.

This then will produce an infinite recursion error on either of those two entries:

```
>>> get_path(tree['bar,server 1'], tree)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in get_path
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in get_path
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in get_path
  [Previous line repeated 994 more times]
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in get_path
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

You can detect such cycles *early* and exit with a clearer error message:

```
def get_path(node, tree, seen=None):
    if seen is None:
        seen = set()
    parent = node.get('parent')
    if parent:
        if  parent in seen:
            raise ValueError(
                'Already handled {!r}, cycle detected. '
                'Check all of {}'.format(
                    parent, sorted(seen)))
        seen.add(parent)
    node_login = '{0[login]},{0[server_id]}'.format(node)  # cleaner method to generate the key
    if not parent:
        return []
    elif parent == node_login:
        return [parent]
    path = get_path(tree[parent], tree, seen)  # pass seen along to recursive calls
    return [parent] + path
```

Running this updated version on the same `tree` now produces:

```
>>> get_path(tree['bar,server 1'], tree)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 16, in get_path
  File "<stdin>", line 16, in get_path
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in get_path
ValueError: Already handled 'foo,server 1', cycle detected. Check all of ['bar,server 1', 'foo,server 1']fted by one space
```

I assumed that such cycles are errors. If they are not, simply return the path up to that point with `if  parent in seen: return []` (so ignore the cycle), but you'll have a version of the path for every member of the cycle, each path a rotated version of the next.

You should really fix your account information, and remove such cycles. If you need to find *all* such cycles, you could use:

```
from collections import deque

def find_all_cycles(tree):
    visited, cycles, path = set(), [], []
    queue = deque(sorted(tree))
    while queue:
        key = queue.pop()
        if key in visited:
            continue
        visited.add(key)
        path.append(key)
        parent = tree[key].get('parent')
        if not parent:
            path = []
        elif parent in visited:
            # cycle detected!
            cycles.append(path + [parent])
            path = []
        else:
            queue.append(parent)
    return cycles
```

Comment: what i have to pass instead of seen parameters?

Comment: @ionluchian: you could pass in a tree without cyclic references, but detecting such references requires a function like this *anyway*. Why the reluctance to do this?

Comment: still experimenting around to fix the recursion, will try now your last function

Comment: Thanks a lot @Martijn Pieters, the new get pah function helped me to ged rid of the error

Comment: Hope all the situations are covered

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message what fixed it for me was to pass the model instead of returning it.

I had to use this:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

The code below did not allow the model to be passed to other models.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self}"
```